# Top user of day, week, all time - best way to implement?

Tags: django, database-design, web-applications

Suppose each user on my site has a score which increases as they use the site (like Stackoverflow) and I have a field `score` stored in the user profile table for each user.

Getting the top 10 users of all time is easy, just order by the `score` column.

I want to have "top 10 today", "top 10 this week", "top 10 of all time".

What's the best way to implement this? Do I need to store every single score change with a timestamp?

Comment: "Do I need to store every single score change with a timestamp?" -- That's what stackoverflow seems to do.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to have a table that stored the increments and use a timestamp. I.E.

```
CREATE TABLE ScoreIncreases (
             PrimaryKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
             UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
             ScoreIncrease INT,
             CreatedDate DATETIME)
```

Your query would then be something like

```
SELECT TOP 1 u.PrimaryKey, SUM(ScoreIncrease)
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN ScoreIncreases si ON si.Userid=u.PrimaryKey
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,si.CreatedDate,GETDATE()) = 0
GROUP BY u.PrimaryKey
ORDER BY SUM(ScoreIncrease) DESC
```